# Microsoft FACE API for android- Error in Sample app

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Cognitive-Face-Android sample app found in github (https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android).

My subscription key is working after getting help from @huxuan. However, when I try to run in the android emulator to do a "Detection" or "Add a group" in the Identification, both get an error.

The picture is in jpeg format and size is 54KB which complies with the limits specified in the FACE API documentation.

Can anyone tell me what is the fix to this?

[image]

Comment: According to the conversation below, this error is mostly a typo problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the sample app and run it on an emulator, and used a JPG image downloaded from the web, and stored both in the `Downloads` folder and the SD card, and it works alright.

Regarding the issue you mentioned in the GitHub thread about `Access denied. Invalid subsription key`, make sure that on file

```
app\src\main\java\com\microsoft\projectoxford\face\samples\helper\SampleApp.java
```

you change this line

```
sFaceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient(getString(R.string.subscription_key));
```

to this:

```
sFaceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0",getString(R.string.subscription_key));
```

(or whatever region your API key is valid for).

[image: android emulator]

Comment: Thank you Maria.  Subscription key is working.  Even when using my actual phone as my emulator and taking a picture from the camera, I get the same error I posted.

Comment: Hi Maria - It finally worked.  I missed out the s in the line. When I copied exactly what you placed here, it started to work. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: `I missed out the s in the line.` What `s`, exactly? :)

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I suspect he changes the variable name to `FaceServiceClient` (without leading `s`) which cause the null object reference problem.